# Using Vue.js in a standalone project

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I am trying to learn Vue.js for work, and I seem to have the syntax down, but I have a question about creating an overall project.

So far, to create a project, I have had to use npm to create the project (or start the ui, and do it from there).

But I am wondering how I can include Vue without always running serve via command prompt to render it in my browser. For example, if I am creating a website front end with html, css, and some javascript, can I somehow import Vue to that and use it?

I assume with something like this:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-multiselect@2.1.0"></script>
```

Comment: I should add: If someone could point me to a direction where I can look at a template that would incorporate html, css, and javascript/vue in one file. That would be great!

Comment: Are you looking for single file components? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: Well that shows Vue examples in a .vue file. I was hoping to just have my .css files, my .html files, and .js files (or a compilation of all three into one file) and incorporate Vue into that. Instead of creating a Vue project.

Comment: Oh, that's not how I understood your original comment. Then just load VueJS from any CDN, that should work fine, e.g. from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.22/vue.min.js

Comment: Just deleted my last comment. Thanks. So I can load that from cdn, and put it into my html file, and then use Vue code?

Comment: Yup. If you try to create a code snippet on SO and load VueJS that's exactly what it does anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this link will help you.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started

#### A little exemple.

##### Html file.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.21/dist/vue.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <p>{{ message }}</p>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

##### Pure js file.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  }
})
```

---

But if you have a **.vue** files like this:

```
<template>
  <!- ... ->
</template>
<script>
  // ...
</script>
```

You don't have the choice, you need to run the script `npm run serve` or `yarn serve` for compiling the **.vue** file into a valid javascript file.